# Python3.6's urlopen call 403s for “some” URLs

Tags: python, ssl, urllib, urlopen

I am using python3.6. 
urlcode.urlopen call fails with 403 for some URLs, but not all.
Examples:

---

WORKS:

```
resp=urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request("https://www.bloomberg.com"), context=ssl._create_unverified_context(),timeout=5)
resp=urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request("https://www.google.com"), context=ssl._create_unverified_context(),timeout=5)
```

DOES NOT WORK, RETURNS 403:

```
resp=urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request("https://www.fox.com"), context=ssl._create_unverified_context(),timeout=5)
resp=urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request("https://www.sciencedaily.com"), context=ssl._create_unverified_context(),timeout=5)
```

---

I am pretty sure it has something to do with certificates and me using an unverified context, but I am curious why it works for some URLs, not all.

I am more interested in a solution that will work for all valid URLs like the ones that do not work above.

Thank you!

Comment: 403 is an HTTP error, so far after the TLS handshake, except if it is generated locally. So you should first have a look/display the full message (HTTP headers) you get back. Also I see no reason to disable checking certificates, so do not do that.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ ?

Comment: What’s in the response body when you get a 403? This should be the first thing you look at.

Comment: This is in the headers in the "except" handling the HTTPError:
`HTTPError: Cache-Control: no-cachePragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Proxy-Connection: close
Connection: close
Content-Length: 606`